# Python telegram bot - problem sending messages through the bot to a chat as if they were from a user

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

Im creating a telegram bot and im stuck with one problem.

After launching the bot, it sends me two buttons, "yes" and "no." I press one of them, and I want my response to remain in the chat under my name.

So as a beginner i dont have as much information as i need.

In my code, errors occurred, particularly issues with data types and function arguments. When I used `bot.send_message` in the callback handling function, errors arose because this function doesn't directly accept the `from_user` argument. The maximum I could achieve was having the bot send a response in its name, not mine. Therefore, I needed to use another method to pass user data so that the bot could send a message as if it were from me. But I don't know which one.

Thank you in advance for any response. |

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
#from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup,InlineKeyboardButton

bot = telebot.TeleBot('mytoken')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('да', callback_data='yes')
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('нет', callback_data='no')
    markup.row(btn1, btn2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'привет, {message.from_user.first_name}! придет ли сегодня Кевин?', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    if callback.data == 'yes':
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'ок, спасибо, что предупредил')
    elif callback.data == 'no':
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'ок, спасибо, что предупредил')

bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Telegram, you can't send a message as if it's from the user directly through the bot API. Messages sent via a bot will always be from the bot itself. However, you can create an illusion that the bot is interacting as the user by editing the original message to include a response.

Here's an example of how you might achieve this:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('your_token')

# Dictionary to store the user's messages
user_responses = {}

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Yes', callback_data='yes')
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('No', callback_data='no')
    markup.row(btn1, btn2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Hello, {message.from_user.first_name}! Will Kevin come today?', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    user_id = callback.from_user.id
    chat_id = callback.message.chat.id

    if callback.data == 'yes':
        user_responses[user_id] = 'Yes, Kevin will come today.'
    elif callback.data == 'no':
        user_responses[user_id] = 'No, Kevin will not come today.'

    # Edit the original message to include the user's response
    if user_id in user_responses:
        bot.edit_message_text(user_responses[user_id], chat_id, callback.message.message_id)

bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

This code stores the user's response in a dictionary user_responses indexed by the user's ID. When the user clicks on 'Yes' or 'No', it updates the user's response in the dictionary and edits the original message to include the user's response. This creates an impression that the user is responding directly. However, it's actually the bot editing its original message to include the user's reply.